# How do I set PdfView to take all the entire screen Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, pdf-viewer, androidpdfviewer

I have a problem I want my PdfView to fit 100% of the screen
Currently I'm using [flutter_pdfview 1.2.2](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdfview)

I have tried to wrap the `PDFView()` with `Container` and give it `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height & width`
but isn't working

**My Code :**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("PDfViewer"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isSaved = !isSaved;
                  if (isSaved) {
                    bookmarkAdded.add(widget.indexPage);
                  }
                });
              },
              icon: Icon(
                isSaved ? Icons.bookmark : Icons.bookmark_border,
                size: 30,
              ))
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: PDFView(
          fitPolicy: FitPolicy.BOTH,
          defaultPage: widget.indexPage,
          nightMode: true,
          autoSpacing: false,
          enableSwipe: false,
          swipeHorizontal: true,
          pageSnap: true,
          filePath: widget.file.path,
          onRender: (pages) => setState(() {
            this.pages = pages!;
            // print("Pages : ${this.pages}");
          }),
          onViewCreated: (controller) => setState(() {
            pdfViewController = controller;
          }),
          onPageChanged: (indexPage, _) => setState(() {
            this.widget.indexPage = indexPage!;
            print('IndexPages : ${widget.indexPage}');
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**UI samples**

[How It is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBXnO.png)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhLzU.png)

Comment: try to wrap pdf view with Expanded widget